# How do you create custom metamodels for parametric types in Perl 6?

Tags: types, metaprogramming, raku, parametric-polymorphism

I'm writing a library for creating monads in Perl 6. Since using just regular parametric roles makes it impossible to extend monads properly (to the best of my knowledge), I decided to create a custom metamodel class that extends `Metamodel::ParametricRoleHOW` and introduce special syntax for creating monads. The problem is when I try to write `monad MonadName[::T]`, this happens:

```
bastille% perl6 monad-test.p6
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling /home/morfent/Documents/p6-Monad/monad-test.p6
Unable to parse monad definition
at /home/morfent/Documents/p6-Monad/monad-test.p6:8
------> monad Identity⏏[::T] {
    expecting any of:
        generic role
```

And when I just write `monad Identity { ... }`, it throws when trying to specialize the type. How can I write this so monads are parametric? Monads don't *have* to extend roles' metamodel exactly, but I'd prefer it were possible to use `does` with monads rather than `is`. Also, even though I already know how to do this, others may not since I don't think it's documented, so if you could include how to make any type parametric in general in your answer that would make this a better reference.

This is what my code for creating monads looks like at the moment:

```
use v6.d;

class Type::MonadHOW is Metamodel::ParametricRoleHOW {
    has Int $!feature_flags;

    my enum FeatureFlags (
        Value  => 0x1,
        Bind   => 0x2,
        Then   => 0x4,
        Return => 0x8
    );

    method !set_value(\M, Attribute:D $attr) {
        self.Metamodel::ParametricRoleHOW::add_attribute: M, $attr;
        $!feature_flags +|= Value;
        self
    }

    method !set_bind(\M, &bind) {
        self.Metamodel::ParametricRoleHOW::add_method: M, 'bind', &bind;
        $!feature_flags +|= Bind;
        self
    }

    method !set_then(\M, &then) {
        self.Metamodel::ParametricRoleHOW::add_method: M, 'then', &then;
        $!feature_flags +|= Then;
        self
    }

    method !set_return(\M, &return) {
        self.Metamodel::ParametricRoleHOW::add_method: M, 'return', &return;
        $!feature_flags +|= Return;
        self
    }

    method new_type(|args) {
        my \M = self.Metamodel::ParametricRoleHOW::new_type: |args;
        M.HOW.HOW.get_attribute_for_usage(M.HOW, '$!feature_flags').set_value(M.HOW, 0);
        M
    }

    method add_attribute(\M, Attribute:D $attr) {
        given $attr.name {
            when '$!value' { self!set_value: M, $attr }
            default        {
                self.Metamodel::ParametricRoleHOW::add_attribute: M, $attr
            }
        }
    }

    method add_method(\M, $name, &method) {
        given $name {
            when 'bind'   { self!set_bind:   \M, &method }
            when 'then'   { self!set_then:   \M, &method }
            when 'return' { self!set_return: \M, &method }
            default       {
                self.Metamodel::ParametricRoleHOW::add_method: \M, $name, &method
            }
        }
    }

    method compose(\M, :$compiler_services) {
        die "Monads must implement a private value attribute."
            unless $!feature_flags +& Value;
        die "Monads must implement a bind method."
            unless $!feature_flags +& Bind;
        die "Monads must implement a then method."
            unless $!feature_flags +& Then;
        die "Monads must implement a return method."
            unless $!feature_flags +& Return;
        self.Metamodel::ParametricRoleHOW::compose: M, :$compiler_services
    }
}

subset Monad is export where *.HOW.WHAT ~~ Type::MonadHOW;

proto sub infix:«>>=»(|) is export {*}
multi sub infix:«>>=»(Monad:D $monad, Mu &f) {
    $monad.bind: &f
}

proto sub infix:«>>»(|) is export {*}
multi sub infix:«>>»(Monad:D $monad, Monad:D $next) {
    $monad.then: $next
}

proto sub pure(|) is export {*}

my package EXPORTHOW {
    package DECLARE {
        constant monad = Type::MonadHOW;
    }
}
```

If my `Monad` subset can also be written so it can be parametric (ideally without creating another custom metamodel class), that would be helpful as well.

Edit: the reason I say monads can't be extended when implementing them as roles rather than having to write a custom meta-class for them is because it was impossible to write monads that are sum types, such as `Maybe`, without duplicating code. Using roles, `Monad[::T]` would look like this:

```
role Monad[::T] {
    has T $!value;

    method ACCEPTS(::?ROLE: ::?ROLE $m --> Bool:D) {
        $!value ~~ $m.^get_attribute_for_usage('$!value').get_value($m)
    }

    submethod BUILD(::?ROLE: T :$!value) {}

    method return(::?ROLE: T --> ::?ROLE)               { ... }
    method bind(::?ROLE: Callable[::?ROLE] --> ::?ROLE) { ... }
    method then(::?ROLE: ::?ROLE --> ::?ROLE)           { ... }
}
```

For example, this is how the identity monad would be implemented using `Monad[T]`:

```
role Identity[::T] does Monad[T] {
    method return(Identity: T $value --> Identity:D) {
        self.bless: :$value
    }
    method bind(Identity:D: Identity:D &f --> Identity:D) {
        &f($!value)
    }
    method then(Identity:D: Identity:D $m --> Identity:D) {
        $m
    }
}
```

Now, for a `Maybe` monad, you'd want to be able to have `Just[T]` and `Nothing[T]` extend it like so:

```
role Maybe[::T] does Monad[T] {
    method return(Maybe: T $value --> ::?ROLE) {
        ::?ROLE[T].bless: :$value
    }
    method bind(Maybe:D: Maybe:D &f --> Maybe:D) {
        &f($!value)
    }
    method then(Maybe:D: Maybe:D $m --> Maybe:D) {
        $m
    }
}
role Just[::T]    does Maybe[T] {}
role Nothing[::T] does Maybe[T] {}
```

The problem here is because the methods are stubbed to use `::?ROLE` in `Monad[T]`, this won't work without there being some way to differentiate between monads and regular roles. With a custom meta-class for monads as well as introducing special syntax for declaring them using `monad` and targeting them from within package declarators with `$?MONAD`/`::?MONAD`, you could define `Maybe[T]` as a role, then be able to implement `Just[T]` and `Nothing[T]` as monads that do `Maybe[T]`.

Comment: What about a variant of `role A[::T] { method foo (T:) { say T } }; role B { ... }; role B does A[B] {}; B.new.foo; # (B)`?

Comment: And if a variation on that won't do the trick nicely enough for your taste, the description in [Composer meta-object API](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/e9351cbaa961c4d1e4ef8b4cb52418d55766a8d6/docs/metamodel.pod#composer-meta-object-api) leads me to think you could just implement a custom `apply` that composes roles with whatever composition strategy you prefer. Hmm. Though reading on I'm not so sure...

Comment: This would probably make it possible to implement `Maybe`, but there's a bigger issue with how roles work that makes any monad constraining two or more types, like `Reader`, impossible to write the same way as in Haskell this way: you can't curry them by parameterizing them with less types than they were declared with, as `Metamodel::ParametricRoleGroupHOW` doesn't allow that. You need at least two custom meta-classes that handle parameterization differently in order for that to be possible, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: "you can't curry them by parameterizing them with less types than they were declared with". I thought that was what [`CurriedRoleHow`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/6c02354633aec4f1ef146c7adb487397b4c4902b/src/Perl6/Metamodel/CurriedRoleHOW.nqp) was for. To be clear, I'm out of my depth, just quacking...